# BuildUrlFromExpression Adding Area to Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, html-helper

I have a site with an admin area and I have created a HTML Helper to help me create images of different sizes in my views, with the following.

```
Html.Image<ImageController>(c => c.DisplayImage(img.Filename, 53, 35), "Product Thumbnail")
```

This is my helper,

```
public static string Image<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Action<T>> action,string alt) where T : Controller
    {
        string url = LinkExtensions.BuildUrlFromExpression(helper, action);
        return string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"{1}\" />", url, alt);
    }
```

The problem I am having is the line `string url = LinkExtensions.BuildUrlFromExpression(helper, action);` is adding the admin area to the url.

Eg `http://localhost:57771/Admin/Image/DisplayImage?....`
Instead of `http://localhost:57771/Image/DisplayImage?....`

I believe it is related to [this](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7764) reported issue, but the workaround submitted is not compiling for me. Not sure where to go from here, any help would be great.

Comment: I've solved this by adding `area = string.Empty` in the `RouteValueDictionary`, which didn't feel like the prettiest solution but it works.

Comment: I have decided to drop the nice and pretty helper for now :(. Instead I am using a standard image tag with the image url pointing to my action. @Mike I'm give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 1):

I have better answer!

```
    public static string Image<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Action<T>> action, int width, int height, string alt)
            where T : Controller
    {
        var expression = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        string actionMethodName = string.Empty;
        if (expression != null)
        {
            actionMethodName = expression.Method.Name;
        }
        string url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection).Action(actionMethodName, typeof(T).Name.Remove(typeof(T).Name.IndexOf("Controller"))).ToString();         
        //string url = LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression<T>(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection, action);
        return string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" width=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" alt=\"{3}\" />", url, width, height, alt);
    }
}
```